# jQuery data attribute value missing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two data attributes in `<option>`, Which have the `lat` and `lng` for the map:

```
<option id="riderInfo" data-lat="" data-lng=""></option>
```

Jquery :

```
var lat = $("#riderInfo").val($(this).data('lat'));
var lng = $("#riderInfo").val($(this).data('lng'));
```

I am printing its value :

```
console.log(lat)
```

The actual code to get value from the select and give to the map, So map will chnage to the given location.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lat = $("#riderInfo").val($(this).data('lat'));
  var lng = $("#riderInfo").val($(this).data('lng'));
  console.log(lat);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
  function init() {
     var locations = [
        ['Rider', 33.686073, 73.0175017, 3]
      ];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.68, 73.01),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var marker, i;
      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      }
  }
});
```

Result of `console.log(lat)` is :

```
[option#riderInfo, context: document, selector: "#riderInfo"]
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What is `this`? What is the value of `data-lat` and `data-lng` What is that result supposed to be showing, and how are you checking it? What is the HTML? Why are you setting the same value twice? The first call is completely redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated the question, And you were right the question was not clear

Comment: #riderInfo can't be 'this' I assume you just want to switch it to the value, so try  `$("#riderInfo").val($('#riderInfo').data('lat'))`

Comment: Your first two lines are confusing. Are you trying to get or set the value?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want to get the data and give it to the map.

Comment: The data from the selected `option` element?

Comment: Yes @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @nodws Same results..........

Answer (score 1):

By setting the value using jquery, jquery object of element is returned and set as variable. you should be using:

```
var lat = $('#riderInfo').data('lat');
var lng = $('#riderInfo').data('lng');
```

Comment: No. `$("#riderInfo").val($(this).data('lat'));` will return jquery object of element `"#riderInfo`.

Comment: You can log this in console `$('input:eq(1)').val('koala')` and check

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. We're coming at this in different ways. You're assuming OP is trying to get the data value in `lat`. I was assuming they're trying to set the `val()` of the element. It's really not clear what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lat = parseFloat($("#riderInfo").data('lat'));
  var lng = parseFloat($("#riderInfo").data('lng'));
  console.log(lat);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
  function init() {
     var locations = [
        ['Rider', lat, lng, 3]
      ];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var marker, i;
      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      }
  }
});
```

Get the data values of `lat`, `lng` into the variable & use it in map function

Hope this will help you.